# recursive max function for list of list python

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive function in order to find the max integer in a list of list. I know how to write a func for list of ints. Can anyone give me some tips for this?I
I am thinking doing it with no Max function. 
ex. a = [1, [2,3], 4, [[2], 1]]
find_max(a) ->4

Comment: However It's not a good question for SO , but please specify some samples for better undestanding into your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through your list and call the `MAX()` function if data type is a list:

```
l = [[54,65,464,656,5],[568,49,7,8,4,3,3515],[312,64,598,46]]

def MAX(l):
    mx = None
    for item in l:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            tmp = MAX(item)
        else:
           tmp = item

       if mx < tmp:
          mx = tmp
    return mx
```

Comment: @bxlt I am glad to help you.Feel free to accept one answer (for the community).

Comment: This will return -1 if all the numbers in the list are negative values below -1.

Comment: @pjs His list contain only positive numbers.Thank you for this observation.

Comment: @WoLy His *example* list contained only positive numbers.  His description said "ints", not positive ints.  A valid algorithm should deal with all cases.  Yours can be fixed, but isn't general as-written.

Comment: @pjs Thank you for this reply.Please if you have time help us to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to tackle this with pure recursion, no loops.  The following seems to do the trick for me:

```
def find_max(a_list):
    l = len(a_list)
    if l > 1:   # if there are multiple elements...
        l /= 2      # find the midpoint
        m1 = find_max(a_list[:l])   # find the max in the first half
        m2 = find_max(a_list[l:])   # find the max in the second half
        if m1 > m2:         # pick between them
            return m1
        else:
            return m2
    elif l < 1: # deal with empty lists
        return None
    else:       # we're down to one element...
        if isinstance(a_list[0], list):     # ...but it may be a list
            return find_max(a_list[0])      # if so, find its max
        else:
            return a_list[0]   # otherwise, a single element is trivially the max of its subset
```

Note that by splitting the subproblems in half rather than reducing by 1, this implementation should be robust against stack overflows even with large lists.

---

Now revised to deal with empty lists.

Comment: its really helpful!!! i was trying to write the function in this way, but i failed. XD

Comment: what if there is an empty sublist?